# Proof by contraposition not making sense

Tags: logic

I fail to understand why contraposition works intuitively. Take this sentence 
for example:

> $\text{If I pass my exams then I am a good student.}$
>
> $\text{I pass my exams }\implies\text{ I am a good student.}$

If I know I passed my exams then I know I am a good student **but** if I didn't pass my exams then I don't really know if I'm a good student or not (since this is implication and not an *if-and-only-if* statement ) and $F\implies T,F\implies F$ are both true, so either outcomes is possible.

Having said this I don't understand why proof by contraposition works. Proof by contraposition would say:

> $\text{I didn't pass my exams }\implies\text{ I am not a good student.}$

But I don't understand **why**? Having not passed my exams doesn't say anything about whether I am a good student or not, and contraposition seems only obvious to me when :

> $\text{I pass my exams }\iff\text{ I am a good student.}$

Then yes, the contrapositive makes intuitive sense to me. But why does it hold for implication as well?

Comment: The contrapositive of $\;A\to B\;$ is $\;\neg B\to \neg A\;$ , **not** $\;\neg A\to\neg B\;$

Comment: Actually, by contraposition you should say "I am not a good student $\Longrightarrow$ I didn't pass my exams", not the other way around.

Comment: Contrapositive: "I am not a good student $\implies$ I don't pass my exams" which is the same as (do the truth table) "I pass my exams $\implies$ I am a good student"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note the following:

- $P\to Q\qquad$ [Primary statemet]
- $Q\to P\qquad$ [Converse]
- $\neg P\to\neg Q\qquad$ [Inverse]
- $\neg Q\to\neg P\qquad$ [Contrapositive]

These are the various terms for the different forms above. Oftentimes, one will be required (as a rudimentary exercise) to show that the primary statement is logically equivalent to the contrapositive; that is, $P\to Q\equiv \neg Q\to\neg P$. Hence, oftentimes, if it seems to be quite difficult to prove that $P\to Q$, then one may resort to proving the contrapositive, i.e. $\neg Q\to\neg P$, thus proving $P\to Q$.

When you are dealing with a linguistic problem, as in your case, I think it is often a good idea to express your conditional with propositions:

- $P:$ I pass my exams.
- $Q:$ I am a good student.

As you noted, you have a claim of the form $P\to Q$. Thus, an equivalent claim to $P\to Q$ would be $\neg Q\to\neg P$, the contrapositive: "If I am not a good student, then I will not pass my exams." What you have done is expressed the **inverse**, which is $\neg P\to\neg Q$: "If I did not pass my exams, then I am not a good student." This is not valid because, in general, $P\to Q\not\equiv\neg P\to\neg Q$. I would encourage you to use truth tables to see why. What you are looking for is the *contrapositive*, and that actually is equivalent to your original statement.

Answer (score 6):

The contrapositive of $A \implies B$ is $\sim B \implies \sim A$.

This has got nothing to do with $B \implies A$ or $\sim A \implies \sim B$, which is the converse of the statement $A \implies B$.

In your case, the contrapositive of the statement

> If I pass my exams then I am a good student.

is

> If I am not a good student then I will not pass my exam.

The statement you have written, i.e.,

> I didn't pass my exams $\implies$ I am not a good student.

is not the contrapositive. It is in fact the converse of your initial statement.

Comment: The converse of $p\to q$ is $q\to p$, not $\neg p\to\neg q$. The latter is called the inverse. Might want to clean that up just to shore things up entirely. :)

Comment: meh, inverse and converse are logically equivalent anyway...

Comment: @MagicMan Well. Inverse and Converse do not really make a difference to me.

Comment: Unless you are writing your answer for your own edification, the difference between converse and inverse *does* matter for someone who clearly is just starting to grasp the fundamentals. It's misleading.

Comment: @MagicMan OK. ${}{}$